# Can I complete 100% bestiary on my first planet, no matter my seed?

Tags: terraria

Bestiary is per world:

> Bestiary progress is tied to a world, not a character ([source](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Bestiary)).

And I was thinking about [crimson](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Crimson) and [corruption](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Corruption) creatures, where I can create new world, get missing in my world blocks and just bring them into mine. It should work in theory (confirm?).

But what about other cases? Killing Skeletron before Dungeon Defender? What else?

Is it **always possible**? Or should I be careful with something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always complete the Bestiary, but you will also need enemies from the other type of evil. This includes the evil-specific bosses, the Eater of Worlds and the Brain of Cthulhu.

You can accomplish this by taking some Ebonstone or Crimstone from a different world, or by purchasing the appropriate seeds from the Dryad. Once in hardmode, the Dryad will sell seeds for the evil that is not native to your world if she's in a graveyard biome, created by placing six or more tombstones close to each other.

Some NPCs and enemies require the ingame Halloween or Christmas events in order to spawn, which are normally only available in accordance to your system's clock. It is possible, however, to trigger a single ingame day of Halloween or Christmas by defeating the Pumpkin Moon or the Frost Moon respectively.

The entries for the only two missable enemies, the Dungeon Guardian and the Tortured Soul, can be obtained by talking to the Clothier and Tax Collector NPCs respectively. Every other enemy that was missable prior to 1.4 (due to being exclusive to worlds pre-hardmode) can now be found in hard mode as well.

Comment: I think this answer could be improved by adding a short explanation for how to create an artificial crimson/corruption biome capable of spawning mobs. I think some readers might not be aware that this is possible and how it is possible.

Comment: @Philipp, creating biomes is fairly easy. I was just using [vile powder](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Vile_Powder) in my crimson world (corruption blocks at start) and with 10x monster spawn rate (in journey mode) it was quick. I just did 100% bestiary without external cheats or editors. I was afraid I have to wait for [Christmas](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Christmas), but it's possible to trigger Santa and christmass for one day anytime.

Comment: @Sinatr I know that, but I wonder how many of the readers of this answer know that.

Comment: Using powders is faster way to create biomes than blocks, remember you will need many minibiomes: corrupted ice caverns, corrupted underground, corrupted desert (with sandstorm) and corrupted desert caverns (maybe more and I am talking about crimson world as base). Certain creatures only spawn offscreen, so it must be made big enough. And creating world with opposite evil if faster to collect ingredients (to summon boss and to make minibiomes) than using graveyard+dryad+seeds trick (you have to wait until it corrupt stone/sand/ice blocks or what?)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the world. If your world is an old world prior to 1.3, and underground desert biome is not generated, and therefore you are not able to find those creatures. You are unable to create artificial Underground desert biome, but again, you can use TEdit to modify your world and add that biome to finish up the bestiary.